# How to build the telegram Bot with Ease?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

How to build the telegram Bot with Ease? Will basic programming knowledge and API be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/web3space/tanos

It is simplified for newbies.

You can build layout.json with basic bot steps and store basic info

For more advanced usage you can use app.js file